# Downloading a simple space delimited file with C# yields garbage characters

Tags: c#, encoding, download, filestream, streamwriter

When trying to initiate a download of a fixed width file in C# and opening the downloaded file with notepad the content comes out complete gibberish. See below as an example.

`????????\@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@???????????????????@?????????@????????????@@???????@???????????????????@@@@@@@@@@@??@@@@??@?????????????@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@?????@@@@@@@@@@@@@@??@@???????@??????????k?????@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@?????????????????????`

Here is my code used to perform the download.

```
char[] buffer = new char[2048];
using (var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
{
    using (var tw = new StreamWriter(DESTINATION + subFolder + files[files.Count - 1] + ".txt", false, Encoding.ASCII))
    {
        while (true)
        {
            int readCount = reader.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            if (readCount == 0) break;
            tw.Write(buffer, 0, readCount);
        }
        responseStream.Close();
        tw.Close();
    }
}
```

I'm inclined to say it has something to do with the file encoding.

I've written the same downloader in python and the file downloads as expected with that code. I just can't figure it out with C#.

### Update

The downloaded text still yeilds as garbage but if I import the data *From Text* using Microsoft Excel and set the file origin as *20924: IBM Latin-1* the text is readable. Is there some way of doing this programmatically during the download when the file is made?

### Update

Any of the *IBM* file origin types decode the downloaded data.

Comment: What encoding is the file, you pass in `Encoding.ASCII` what is is supposed to be?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I'm almost 100% sure it's supposed to be ASCII. But with `Encoding.ASCII` in there it returns gibberish. In my python version I don't specify anything and it comes out fine. That's why I'm scratching my head.

Comment: I find it unlikely that Python defaults to ASCII, almost nothing does that today. Everything does Utf-8, Utf-16 (called `Encoding.Unicode` in .net) or Utf-32.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I've tried everyone of those encoding schemes and each one produces garbage whereas the python download does not. When I manually download the file using a client like FileZilla it also produces a readable document.

Comment: Where are you downloading the files from? Just wondering about the reasons behind writing your own download method rather than using one of the many existing ones in .NET?

Comment: @Equalsk the files are being downloaded from a z/OS mainframe.

Comment: If you were to read the bytes in this way (as in `ReadByte()`), are the bytes what you'd expect?

Comment: That's a good question @DangerZone. But I'm not sure how I would check.

Comment: Maybe try opening the file in a hex editor (if you can get your hands on the source) and compare to what `ReadByte()` is giving you? I'm not sure if that'll work, but it makes sense in my head anyway.

Comment: Does z/OS have the same endianess as Windows?

Comment: @ChrisDunaway I don't know but I've tried the `Encoding.BigEndianUnicode` too and still get gibberish.

Comment: @DangerZone way different results using `ReadByte()`

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I've made a discovery and perhaps you can shed some insight? If I set the file origin as 20924: IBM Latin-1 during an Excel *From Text* data import the text is readable in the file preview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(inputFilePath, Encoding.GetEncoding("IBM00924"));
using (reader = File.OpenText(inputFilePath))
{ ... }
```

In case you want to try all available encodings to see what yields readable data, use the [Encoding.GetEncodings()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.getencodings(v=vs.110).aspx) method to iterate over all encodings, like so:

```
foreach (var encoding in Encoding.GetEncodings())
{
    // Read raw
    var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(inputFilePath);
    var converted = Encoding.Convert(encoding, Encoding.Utf8, bytes);
    File.WriteAllText(Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(outputFilePath), encoding.Name + ".txt") converted);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: No dice. Still gibberish when opened with Notepad.

Comment: Maybe set the encoding on the `FileStream()`?

Comment: I agree. But it's sensitive data. Plus it adds to the challenge.

Comment: Is there a way I can read the response stream in every `Encoding.GetEncodings()` and write them to their own individual encoding file?

Comment: This helped. Iterating over all the different encodings lead me to one that worked and I used that for all the downloads.